# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. in a Neural Net

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

i was following a tutorial about neural networks but trying to do it my way, but in the line:

```
_Y[i0,i1]=ForwardPass(Neural_net, np.array([[x0,x1]]))
```

the console say:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

The variables are defined in this block:

```
    res = 50

    _x0=np.linspace(-1.5,1.5,res)
    _x1=np.linspace(-1.5,1.5,res)

    _Y = np.zeros((res,res))

    for i0,x0 in enumerate(_x0):
      for i1,x1 in enumerate(_x1):
        _Y[i0,i1]=ForwardPass(Neural_net, np.array([[x0,x1]]))
```

here is the code of the ForwardPass Function:

```
def ForwardPass(neu_net, ent):

  outs=[ent]

  for l, layer in enumerate(neu_net):

    Sp=outs[-1]@neu_net[l].w + neu_net[l].b
    a=neu_net[l].act_f[0](Sp)

    outs.append(a)
  return outs
```

Comment: Can you also show us the values of `x0,x1 and _Y[i0,i1]` before running the above line.

Comment: @LazyCoder done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to add a print statement inside the iteration to check for the values of _Y[i0,i1]:

```
res = 50

_x0=np.linspace(-1.5,1.5,res)
_x1=np.linspace(-1.5,1.5,res)

_Y = np.zeros((res,res))

for i0,x0 in enumerate(_x0):
    for i1,x1 in enumerate(_x1):
        print(_Y[i0,i1])
>>0.0
  0.0
  0.0
  ..
```

`_Y[i0,i1]` is a floating value while the result coming from `ForwardPass(Neural_net, np.array([[x0,x1]]))` is a list.

Hence as the error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` says its because you're trying to assign a list(array) to a float value(array element)